# Lower bounds for classical counting algorithm

Tags: quantum-computation

This is Exercise 6.14 from Nielsen & Chuang.

Prove that any classical counting algorithm with a probability at least $3/4$ for estimating $M$ correctly to within an accuracy $c\sqrt{M}$ for some constant $c$ and for all values of $M$ must make $\Omega (N)$ oracle calls. Here $N$ is the size of the set, and $M \leq N$ are the number of elements which are the solution to the search problem.

I have been stuck on this problem for some time now. The key point is I do not really see how to do this for "any" classical algorithm. Any help would be much appreciated.

Statement of the Original Problem in Exercise 6.14 of [Page 261, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf)

> Consider a classical algorithm for the counting problem which samples uniformly and
> independently $k$ times from the search space, and let $X_1, ... ,X_k$ be the results of
> the oracle calls, that is, $X_j=1$ if the $j$ th oracle call revealed a solution to the
> problem, and $X_j=0$ if the $j^{th}$ oracle call did not reveal a solution to the problem. This algorithm returns the estimate $S≡N\times\sum_j X_j/k$ for the number of solutions to the search problem. Show that the standard deviation in S is $\Delta S=\sqrt{M (N − M )/k}$. Prove that to obtain a probability at least $3/4$ of estimating $M$ correctly to within an accuracy $\sqrt{M}$ for all values of $M$ we must have $k=\Omega(N)$.

Comment: the only classical methodology that makes sense here is monte carlo ie choose a point at random, see if it is in M, do that a number of times, you have an estimate of the ratio of M elements to N elements. Assuming you know N, you can then estimate M.

Comment: thank you. In that case the proof is easy.